# How to add/edit function to the clear button icon in Material UI Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the code below

```
                   <Autocomplete
                        id='combo-box-demo'
                        options={companies}
                        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
                        renderInput={params => (
                            <TextField {...params} variant='outlined' />
                        )}
                        onChange={(event, newValue) => onCompanyChange(event, newValue)}
                    />
```

I want to customized the function when I clicked on the clear button in the autocomplete input. I need to ask the user if they really wants to clear the field first. Is it possible to target the .MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator so I can add more function on it? Thank is advance!

Comment: You can do `dom-hacking` (as its called in react) but there no particular react way of doing that, you can call it as the inability of that package. If that's ok I will post code

Comment: Yes it is ok, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow this code, although **I display an alert** you can make a `modal` and show that if you wish

**CODE :**

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  setTimeout(async () => {
    const close = await document.getElementsByClassName(
      "MuiAutocomplete-clearIndicator"
    )[0];
    close.addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("Really, clear the input");
    });
  }, 100);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", year: 1980 },
  { title: "Forrest Gump", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Inception", year: 2010 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", year: 2002 },
  { title: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", year: 1975 },
  { title: "Goodfellas", year: 1990 },
  { title: "The Matrix", year: 1999 },
  { title: "Seven Samurai", year: 1954 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode IV - A New Hope", year: 1977 },
  { title: "City of God", year: 2002 },
  { title: "Se7en", year: 1995 },
  { title: "The Silence of the Lambs", year: 1991 },
  { title: "It's a Wonderful Life", year: 1946 },
  { title: "Life Is Beautiful", year: 1997 },
  { title: "The Usual Suspects", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Léon: The Professional", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Spirited Away", year: 2001 },
  { title: "Saving Private Ryan", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in the West", year: 1968 },
  { title: "American History X", year: 1998 },
  { title: "Interstellar", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Casablanca", year: 1942 },
  { title: "City Lights", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Psycho", year: 1960 },
  { title: "The Green Mile", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Intouchables", year: 2011 },
  { title: "Modern Times", year: 1936 },
  { title: "Raiders of the Lost Ark", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Rear Window", year: 1954 },
  { title: "The Pianist", year: 2002 },
  { title: "The Departed", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Terminator 2: Judgment Day", year: 1991 },
  { title: "Back to the Future", year: 1985 },
  { title: "Whiplash", year: 2014 },
  { title: "Gladiator", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Memento", year: 2000 },
  { title: "The Prestige", year: 2006 },
  { title: "The Lion King", year: 1994 },
  { title: "Apocalypse Now", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Alien", year: 1979 },
  { title: "Sunset Boulevard", year: 1950 },
  {
    title:
      "Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb",
    year: 1964
  },
  { title: "The Great Dictator", year: 1940 },
  { title: "Cinema Paradiso", year: 1988 },
  { title: "The Lives of Others", year: 2006 },
  { title: "Grave of the Fireflies", year: 1988 },
  { title: "Paths of Glory", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Django Unchained", year: 2012 },
  { title: "The Shining", year: 1980 },
  { title: "WALL·E", year: 2008 },
  { title: "American Beauty", year: 1999 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight Rises", year: 2012 },
  { title: "Princess Mononoke", year: 1997 },
  { title: "Aliens", year: 1986 },
  { title: "Oldboy", year: 2003 },
  { title: "Once Upon a Time in America", year: 1984 },
  { title: "Witness for the Prosecution", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Das Boot", year: 1981 },
  { title: "Citizen Kane", year: 1941 },
  { title: "North by Northwest", year: 1959 },
  { title: "Vertigo", year: 1958 },
  { title: "Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi", year: 1983 },
  { title: "Reservoir Dogs", year: 1992 },
  { title: "Braveheart", year: 1995 },
  { title: "M", year: 1931 },
  { title: "Requiem for a Dream", year: 2000 },
  { title: "Amélie", year: 2001 },
  { title: "A Clockwork Orange", year: 1971 },
  { title: "Like Stars on Earth", year: 2007 },
  { title: "Taxi Driver", year: 1976 },
  { title: "Lawrence of Arabia", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Double Indemnity", year: 1944 },
  { title: "Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind", year: 2004 },
  { title: "Amadeus", year: 1984 },
  { title: "To Kill a Mockingbird", year: 1962 },
  { title: "Toy Story 3", year: 2010 },
  { title: "Logan", year: 2017 },
  { title: "Full Metal Jacket", year: 1987 },
  { title: "Dangal", year: 2016 },
  { title: "The Sting", year: 1973 },
  { title: "2001: A Space Odyssey", year: 1968 },
  { title: "Singin' in the Rain", year: 1952 },
  { title: "Toy Story", year: 1995 },
  { title: "Bicycle Thieves", year: 1948 },
  { title: "The Kid", year: 1921 },
  { title: "Inglourious Basterds", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Snatch", year: 2000 },
  { title: "3 Idiots", year: 2009 },
  { title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail", year: 1975 }
];
```

If you want a clean looking modal, instead of alert you can set the modal to be visible in the `close.addEventListener`'s second argument (that's the function itself)

You can checkout a working demo in codesandbox here :
[Link to the working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-haze-3qdgg?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 7):

```
const onCompanyChange = (event, value, reason) => {
 if(reason === "clear")
    confirm("Are you sure to clear?"); // or you can open Dialog here
 
 //other codes go here like setting the value of input
};

<Autocomplete
             id='combo-box-demo'
             options={companies}
             getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
             renderInput={params => (
                           <TextField {...params} variant='outlined' />
                         )}
             onChange={onCompanyChange}
             />
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer works, Whoever wondering why, it is in the documentation [onchange](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/autocomplete/#Autocomplete-prop-onChange)

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this code and handle your clear button by function. just use `clearIcon` prop and use `IconButton` in this prop...

```
    <Autocomplete
        clearIcon={
               <IconButton
                  onClick={() => setCompaniesId('')}
                  sx={{
                    width: '1.5rem',
                    height: '1.5rem',}}>
                  <CloseIcon />
              </IconButton>}
        id='combo-box-demo'
        options={companies}
        getOptionLabel={getOptionLabel}
        renderInput={params => <TextField {...params} variant='outlined'/>}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => onCompanyChange(event, newValue)}
        />
```